# Реализовать generic для двух интерфейсов

Tags: java, generics

Как реализовать generic для двух интерфейсов с возможностью затем использовать его в качестве любого из этих типов. Интересует использование этого generic для элементов List.

Код для понимания, что у меня не получается и что я хочу получить в конечном итоге:

```
public class Container<T extends Container.IFoo & Container.IBar> {

    private List<T> mList;

    public Container() {
        mList = new ArrayList<MultiInterfacesClass>();
    }

    public List<IFoo> getIFooList() {
        return mList;
    }

    public List<IBar> getIBarList() {
        return mList;
    }

    public interface IFoo {
        void foo();
    }

    public interface IBar {
        void bar();
    }

    public static class MultiInterfacesClass implements IFoo, IBar {


        @Override
        public void bar() {

        }

        @Override
        public void foo() {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно написать

```
public List<? extends IFoo> getIFooList() {
    return mList;
}
```

`List<? extends IFoo>` - это список элементов какого-то класса, расширяющего `IFoo`. Поскольку тип `T extends Container.IFoo & Container.IBar` расширяет `IFoo`, список `List<T>` - подходит, и его можно вернуть.

Код:

```
Container<MultiInterfacesClass> container = new Container<>();

List<? extends IFoo> list = container.getIFooList();
IFoo foo = list.get( 0 );
```

скомпилируется, но сделать

```
container.getIFooList().add( foo );
```

уже не получится. Использование типа `? extends IFoo` не даст вызвать `add` с аргументом, отличным от `null`, и это хорошо, т.к. наш список на самом деле содержит объекты `T extends Container.IFoo & Container.IBar`, а не любых наследников `IFoo`:

```
IFoo someFoo = new IFoo() { 
    public void foo() {} 
};
container.getIFooList().add( someFoo );

IBar someBar = container.getIBarList().get( 0 );
```

Код мог бы вызвать `ClassCastException` во время выполнения, при присвоении `someBar`, но просто не скомпилируется.

---

Конструктор нужно переписать, как

```
public Container() {
    mList = new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

либо объявить `private List<? extends T> mList;`

Comment: То есть добавить в этот список объект класса MultiInterfacesClass невозможно?

Comment: @Lucky_spirit нет. Просто нельзя вызвать методы с аргументами типа `? extends Something`.

Comment: я нашёл выход только, если сам класс Container не параметризовать и объявить сразу private List<MultiInterfacesClass> mList. А вот методы getIFooList() и getIBarList() оставил так, как Вы написали. Получилось не совсем то, что изначально планировал, но похоже. Ещё раз спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Lucky_spirit если `List<T> mValue;`, то вы можете объявить у `Container` метод `add(T value) { mValue.add( value ); }` и он будет работать напр. `new Container<MultiInterfacesClass>().add( new MultiInterfacesClass() )`. А внутри `Container` нельзя написать `T var = new MultiInterfacesClass()`, поскольку `T` может означать другой класс, реализующий `IFoo & IBar`.